# how can I get the youtube shared links from my facebook account?

Tags: iphone, facebook, video, youtube

I want to list the YouTube video links in my iPhone app that I have shared in my facebook account.

How can I do this ?

Please if you have knowledge about this, please share with us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following instruction;

1. make a request for `metadata`.
2. After getting the response for `metadata`, just parse `links` dictionary from `connections`. You will get one `url` with access_token and signature.
3. Make one more request with the `url`.

```
eg:[fbGraph doGraphGetWithUrlString:[[[resultFacebook valueForKey:@"metadata"] valueForKey:@"connections"] valueForKey:@"links"]]
```

4 . Now you will get list of YouTube url from Facebook that already is in your Facebook Wall.

Answer (score 0):

Look at FBConnect [FBConnect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios) and [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/) or [REST API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) to see if this is possible.